# Import PNG to SQL Server (without disk access)

Tags: sql-server, image, import, blob-storage

How can I import a PNG to an SQL Server database installed in a machine where I'm not granted access (except to the DB instance)?

I cannot do the following because I cannot access the disk:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WorkItemState]  (ImageBits)
SELECT  BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET  (BULK 'C:\checkbox.png', SINGLE_BLOB) as MyImage
```

Is there a way to convert the PNG to a recognizable format that I can simply copy/paste on my table column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode your image with base64 like:

`cat YOUR_IMAGE.png | base64` or directly `base64 YOUR_IMAGE.png` and add the output to your database.